# inserting data into oracle database using php

Tags: php, sql, oracle

This is the table when I put value it is not inserted 
when i run the .php file output is data was not inserted...
i cant find the error .what to do?
as i am new in php somebody plz help

**The table**:

```
create table Employee(
E_ID number(10) primary key,
E_First_Name varchar2(10),
E_Last_Name varchar2(10),
E_Gender varchar2(6),
E_address varchar2(20),
E_phone_No number(10),
E_category varchar2(10),
EMP_salary number(20),
work_hour varchar2(20),
Date_Of_Join date
);
```

**The php code page**:

```
<?php
    $conn=oci_connect("system","123","localhost/orcl");
    ob_start();
    $current_file=$_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME'];
    $massage= "";
    if(isset($_POST['E_ID'])&&isset($_POST['E_First_Name'])&&
    isset($_POST['E_Last_Name'])&&isset($_POST['E_Gender'])&&
    isset($_POST['E_address'])&&isset($_POST['E_phone_No'])&&
    isset($_POST['E_category'])&&isset($_POST['EMP_salary'])&&
    isset($_POST['work_hour'])&&isset($_POST['Date_Of_Join']))
    {
        $E_ID = $_POST['E_ID'];
        $E_First_Name= $_POST['E_First_Name'];
        $E_Last_Name = $_POST['E_Last_Name'];
        $E_Gender = $_POST['E_Gender'];
        $E_address = $_POST['E_address'];
        $E_phone_No = $_POST['E_phone_No'];
        $E_category = $_POST['E_category'];
        $EMP_salary = $_POST['EMP_salary'];
                                       $work_hour =$_POST['work_hour'];
                                       $Date_Of_Join=$_POST['Date_Of_Join'];

        if(!empty($E_ID)&&!empty($E_First_Name)&&!empty($E_Last_Name)&&
        !empty($E_Gender)&&!empty($E_address)&&!empty($E_phone_No)&&
        !empty($E_category)&&!empty($EMP_salary)&&!empty( $work_hour)&&!empty($Date_Of_Join))
        {

                $sql = "insert into Employee values('".$E_ID."','".$E_First_Name."','".$E_Last_Name."','".
                $E_Gender."','".$E_address."',".$E_phone_No.",".$E_category .",".$EMP_salary.",".  $work_hour.",".$Date_Of_Join.")";
                //echo $sql.'<br>';
                $stid = oci_parse($conn,$sql);
                $r = @oci_execute($stid);
                if($r)
                {
                    echo ' data is inserted...<br>';
                }
                else
                {
                    echo 'data was not inserted...<br>';
                }

        }
        else
        {
            $massage = "please fill up all the form correctly<br>";
        }
    }

?>
<html>
<head>
<title>Create FoodItem Table</title>
<style>
body
{
background:orange;
}
</style>
<head>
<body>
fill all the forms for inserting data:<br><br>
<?php echo $massage;?>
<hr color="green">
<form action="<?php echo $current_file;?>" method="POST">

    E_ID:<br> <input type="number" name="E_ID" autofocus><br><br>
    E_First_Name:<br> <input type="text" name ="E_First_Name" ><br><br>
    E_Last_Name:<br> <input type="text" name="E_Last_Name" ><br><br>
    E_Gender:<br> <input type="text" name="E_Gender" ><br><br>
    E_address:<br> <input type="text" name ="E_address"><br><br>
    E_phone_No:<br> <input type= "number" name="E_phone_No" ><br><br>
    E_category:<br><input type="text" name="E_category"><br><br>
    EMP_salary:<br><input type="number" name="EMP_salary" ><br><br>
    work_hour:<br><input type="text"name="work_hour"><br><br>
                  Date_Of_Join:<br><input type="text"name="Date_Of_Join"><br><br>
    <input type ="submit" value="Create employee "><br><br>
    <a href="index..php">Home</a>

</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: If it's because of [`my answer`](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22526173/) below, do click the White checkmark next to my answer till it turns Green. That is how the question is closed and considered answered and provided the solution; and Welcome to StackOverflow. @user3440295

Answer (score 1):

This line is missing single quotes around some of the values:

```
('".$E_ID."','".$E_First_Name."','".$E_Last_Name."','".$E_Gender."','".$E_address."', 
".$E_phone_No.", ".$E_category .",".$EMP_salary.",".  $work_hour.",".$Date_Of_Join.")
```

Change it to:

```
('".$E_ID."','".$E_First_Name."','".$E_Last_Name."','". $E_Gender."','".$E_address."', 
'".$E_phone_No."','".$E_category ."','".$EMP_salary."','".$work_hour."','".$Date_Of_Join."')
```